# Launching other programs using a multiprocessing pool in Python is slow

Tags: python, windows, performance, multiprocessing, pool

**My goal:**

Use some function in python to extract data from many datafiles simultanously using different processors on my computer. I need to extract data from 1300 files and would therefore like Python to start extracting data from a new file once one extraction is complete. The extraction of data from a file is completely independent of extraction of data from other files. The files are of a form requiring to open the program which created them (OrcaFlex) to extract data. Due to this, extracting data from a single file can be time-consuming. (I use Windows)

**My attempt:**

Using Multiprocessing.Pool().map_async to pool my tasks.

**Code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import OrcFxAPI # Package connected to external program

arcs = [1,2,5,7,9,13]

# define a example function
def get_results(x):
    # Collects results from external program:
    model = OrcFxAPI.Model(x[0])
    c = model['line_inner_barrel'].LinkedStatistics(['Ezy-Angle'], 1,     objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeEndB).TimeSeriesStatistics('Ezy-Angle').Mean
    d = model['line_inner_barrel'].LinkedStatistics(['Ezy-Angle'], 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeEndB).Query('Ezy-Angle', 'Ezy-Angle').ValueAtMax
    e = model['line_inner_barrel'].LinkedStatistics(['Ezy-Angle'], 1, objectExtra=OrcFxAPI.oeEndB).Query('Ezy-Angle', 'Ezy-Angle').ValueAtMin

# Also does many other operations for extraction of results

return [c,d,e]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # METHOD WITH POOL - TAKES APPROX 1 HR 28 MIN
    # List of input needed for the get_results function:
    args = ((('CaseD%.3d.sim' % casenumber), arcs, 1) for casenumber in range(1,25))

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=7)
    results = pool.map_async(get_results, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # METHOD WITH FOR-LOOP - TAKES APPROX 1 HR 10 MIN
    # List of input needed for the get_results function:
    args2 = ((('CaseD%.3d.sim' % casenumber), arcs, 1) for casenumber in range(1,25))
    for arg in args2:
        get_results(arg)
```

**Problem:**
Using a for-loop for a reduced set (24)` of smaller datafiles took 1 hour 10 min, while using the Pool with 7 processors took 1 hour 28 min. Does anybody know why the run-time is so slow, and not close to divided by seven???

Also, is there a way of knowing which processor the Multiprocessing.Pool() allocates to a given Process? (In other words, can I let my Process know which processor it is using)

All help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Which line(s) actually take a long time to run?  You should profile it and find out, or just add print statements to measure it.  Once you know that you can find out if those parts are implemented in Python or C.  And you can print `os.getpid()` in `get_results()` to see which ones are being run in which processes.

Comment: It's entirely possible that your external library *already* parallelizes its operations, meaning that your processors would be saturated even with 1 process.

Comment: Looks like it does: http://www.orcina.com/SoftwareProducts/OrcaFlex/Documentation/Help/Content/html/ParallelProcessing.htm

Comment: I tried to use os.getpid, but it does not print the results inside the get_results().. Does anybody know why?